# Making clones of HTML divisions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML divisions almost same. I need to add a clone of my first div after the original one, but before the second div.

This is the code I tried.

```
<body>


        <div id="2ndPayDiv">
            <label id="2ndPayLbl">Payment No 2: </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" /> 
        </div>

        <div id ="totPayForm" >
            <label id="2ndPayLbl">Total Payment: </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Add new one"  onclick="addNewField();return false;">
        </div>

        <script>
            var i=3;
            function addNewField() {

                var myDiv = document.getElementById("2ndPayDiv");
                var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true); // the true is for deep cloning

                var totDiv = document.getElementById("totPayForm");
                var parentDiv = totDiv.parentNode;
                parentDiv.insertBefore(divClone, totDiv);

                document.getElementById('2ndPayLbl').innerHTML = 'Payment No '+i++ +':';

            }
        </script>


    </body>
```

my first div is `2ndPayDiv`. I need to have a clone of that after it, but before the div `totPayForm` every time when I click the button.
But it behave unexpectedly. It creates the clone and place it before everything. 
How can I solve this problem

Comment: tagged as `jquery` but there isn't any `jquery` in your code.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I've heard someone calling a `div` as "divisions" :)

Comment: this can be done in one line with jQuery ,  you have a jQuery tag... were you wanting a jquery answer?

Comment: the duplicate `id`s are gonna complicate things

Comment: @northkildonan sorry for that, I have accidentally clicked on the tag which was suggested.

Comment: @guest How can I do this without getting duplicate 'id's?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the `2ndPayDiv` inside a div, and use the `appendChild` ?

```
    <div>
        <div id="2ndPayDiv">
            <label id="2ndPayLbl">Payment No 2: </label>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" /> 
        </div>
    <div>
```

JS:

```
       function addNewField() {

            var myDiv = document.getElementById("2ndPayDiv");
            var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true); // the true is for deep cloning

            var parentDiv = myDiv.parentNode;
            parentDiv.appendChild(divClone);

            document.getElementById('2ndPayLbl').innerHTML = 'Payment No '+i++ +':';

        }
```

Comment: This is not working as expected either. The newly created div is placed before everything and the second last div goes after everything.